# ContraintViolation after upgrade Symfony from 4.2 to 4.3

Tags: symfony4, a2lix-translation

I'm using a2lix_translation with KnpDoctrineExtension.
I have a problem when create or update a record. Before upgrade Symfony to 4.3 works perfectly.

Now I've got this error ConstraintViolation:

Path: data.defaultLocale
Message: "This value should be of type. App\Entity\Returns
Invalid value "en"
Thanks for your help.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: I found the problem. The new feature of sf 4. 3 "auto_mapping: App\Entity\: []" in config/framework.

Comment: to Battista :could you give a little more information on how your fixed your problem? I'm having the same one here.